# Do loop skipping even number

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I represents the global variable i.e the name I represents same  variable  inside and outside the function. Fact is first called when I = 1, which is the first value written. This value is
passed to the function's dummy argument N. The same I is now given the initial value 2 by the DO loop inside Fact, but since it is greater than N, the DO loop is not executed, so I still has the value 2
when Fact returns to be printed in the main program. However, I is now incremented to 3 in the
DO loop in the main program, which is the value it has when the second call to Fact takes place.

```
PROGRAM Factorial 
IMPLICIT NONE 
INTEGER I

DO I = 1, 10 
PRINT*, I, Fact(I) 
END DO

 CONTAINS 
 FUNCTION Fact( N ) 
INTEGER Fact, N, Temp 
Temp = 1 
DO I = 2, N 
  Temp = I * Temp 
END DO 
Fact = Temp 
END FUNCTION 
 END
```

and Once it completes I goes from 2 to N where now N =3..Now the function must returns I =3 to main program such that next I should be 4 in Do loop of main program, but when compiled and run..it only shows factor for 3,5,7 and 9.....My question is why it skip 4 or 6 or 8.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Please fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exiting a loop the control variable gets the value of the upper bound + 1. However, it is illegal to modify the value of a loop control variable and anything can happen if you manage to do that despite the compiler's checks. It is an undefined behaviour then.

---

Not only that, you are aliasing the global I by using it as I as N at the same time inside the function. The compiler can probably perform various optimizations assuming that they are distinct when in fact they refer to the same variable. The program is therefore again *illegal* and unpredictable.

Consider this example and try to compile it with different optimization levels. You will get different answers:

```
i = 1
call s(i)

contains

  subroutine s(j)
    do k = 1, 10
      j = i + j
    end do
    print *, j
  end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBDsIwEAPv@wofKbQSFWfewBtC2lQbog1K0u932YaDJXtsh1xacTJt4W9UGU/M5F1KqBceiHyW5lgqEVD3d8l7Y1mtjIMRYMn4nJ8R870DIFpm3BB7XmWxUbffwtJwHXtjnE6pHj4kt1WdXo8f)

This particular problem can probably be fixed by declaring `i` or the dummy argument `target`.

Comment: I only wanted to learn how it works...I know I should declared I only for main program and another separately...But still i didn't get your answer..that control variable gets the value of the upper bound + 1....Is shouldn't be I =4 and then 5 and 6 and so on..

Comment: @VladimirF Not sure I follow your second paragraph - but the main point is the program is modifying a loop control variable, which makes the whole program illegal. Any output it creates is meaningless and it is pointless trying to interpret it.

Comment: @RadhaKrishna The point is that the program is illegal, as IanBush confirms. There is no poiint whatsoever to trying to understand the result. It is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior If you want to understand the code the compiler created, you should examine the resulting assembly.

Comment: @VladimirF But when executed it shows a pattern..that print out factorial of 1,3,5,7 and but skips even no...so I just want to understand why does it skips even no.

Comment: Most likely  because the very first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @VladimirF Okay I understood..utnill do has value within declared initial and final value..do loop will execute when the index value is greater then declared final value of do loop it executs such that a new value of variable will be the value when the do loop executed i.e greater then the final value. Thanks. that was silly mistake.

Comment: No. Your program is illegal.  Their is no right way to interpret the output as there is no right output. Your program is allowed to print "Aardvark". Your program is allowed to print nothing. Your program is allowed to start World War 3. Your program is allowed to do anything as its behavior is not defined by the relevant language standard, in this case Fortran. That is all.