# three nested do loops when parallelized don't give same results as serial code

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I need to parallelize this piece of code (fortran77) with openmp 4.5.

```
      DO 700 K=1,KMM1
          K1 = KB1(K)
          K2 = KB2(K)
          DO 700 J=2,JM
              JSB= JSBLK(J)
              J1 = JB1(J)
              J2 = JB2(J)
              DO 700 I=1,IMM1
                  I1 = IB1(I)
                  I2 = IB2(I)
                  DELTA = STORE(I,J,K)
                  B1CHG(I1,J1,K1) = B1CHG(I1,J1,K1) + DELTA
                  B2CHG(I2,J2,K2) = B2CHG(I2,J2,K2) + DELTA
                  SBCHG(JSB)      = SBCHG(JSB)      + DELTA
  700 CONTINUE
```

I've used the simple statement !OMP PARALLEL DO ,!OMP END PARALLEL DO before and after the code and checked result, but they are not the same. I've initialized the vectors KB1,KB2,JSBLK,JB1,JB2,IB1,IB2,STORE,B1CHG,B2CHG,SBCHG with random values and in the parallel loop i'm using different name for variables ( for example STOREP instead of STORE), then i check if STOREP==STORE, B1CHGP==B2CHG etc.. If i remove the openmp pragma the results are the same. This is the code I use for compare and testing the serial and parallel version:

```
     PARAMETER(KMM1=10, JM=5 , IMM1=5  )

     COMMON/VEC/ KB1(KMM1),KB2(KMM1),JSBLK(JM),JB1(JM),JB2(JM),
    &            IB1(IMM1),IB2(IMM1),STORE(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
    &            B1CHG(IMM1,JM,KMM1),B2CHG(IMM1,JM,KMM1),SBCHG(JM)

     COMMON/PARVEC/  STOREP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),
    &            B1CHGP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),B2CHGP(IMM1,JM,KMM1),SBCHGP(JM)




     include 'omp_lib.h'




C---------------------------------------------------------------------     
C   INITIALIZING DUMMY ARRAYS
C RANDOM_NUMBER E' UNA SUBROUTINE DEL FORTRAN 95      
     CALL RANDOM_SEED()
     DO 701 K=1,KMM1

         CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(U)
         KB1(K)=FLOOR((KMM1+1)*U)

         CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(U)
         JH = 0 + FLOOR((KMM1+1)*u)
         KB2(K)=JH

         DO 701 J=2,JM

         CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(U)
         JH = 0 + FLOOR((JM+1)*u)
         JSBLK(J)=JH

         CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(U)
         JH =  0 + FLOOR((JM+1)*U)
         JB1(J)=JH

         CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(U)
         JH = 0 + FLOOR((JM+1)*U)
         JB2(J)= JH

         DO 701 I=1,IMM1

             CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(U)
             JH = 0 + FLOOR((IMM1+1)*U)
             IB1(I)=JH


             CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(U)
             JH = 0 + FLOOR((IMM1+1)*U)
             IB2(I)=JH

             CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(STORE(I,J,K))
             CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(B1CHG(I,J,K))
             CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(B2CHG(I,J,K))
             CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(SBCHG(J))

             STOREP(I,J,K) = STORE(I,J,K)
             B1CHGP(I,J,K) = B1CHG(I,J,K)
             B2CHGP(I,J,K) = B2CHG(I,J,K)
             SBCHGP(J)= SBCHG(J)

 701 CONTINUE

C---------------------------------------------------------------------
C PLOTTING THE INITIALIZED ARRAYS FOR VISUAL INSPECTION
     DO 702 K=1,KMM1
         WRITE(6,*) KB1(K),KB2(K) 
         DO 702 J=2,JM
             WRITE(6,*) JSBLK(J),JB1(J),JB2(J)
             DO 702 I=1,IMM1
                 WRITE(6,*) IB1(I),IB2(I),STORE(I,J,K)
                 WRITE(6,*) B1CHG(I,J,K)
                 WRITE(6,*) B2CHG(I,J,K)
                 WRITE(6,*) SBCHG(J)
 702 CONTINUE
C
C
C   NOW THE SERIAL/PARALLEL CODE COMPARING
C
c---------------------------------------------------------------------
C    ENTERING SERIAL REGION    



     SEC1 = omp_get_wtime ( )

     DO 700 K=1,KMM1
         K1 = KB1(K)
         K2 = KB2(K)
         DO 700 J=2,JM
             JSB= JSBLK(J)
             J1 = JB1(J)
             J2 = JB2(J)
             DO 700 I=1,IMM1
                I1 = IB1(I)
                I2 = IB2(I)
                DELTA = STORE(I,J,K)
                B1CHG(I1,J1,K1) = B1CHG(I1,J1,K1) + DELTA
                B2CHG(I2,J2,K2) = B2CHG(I2,J2,K2) + DELTA
                SBCHG(JSB)      = SBCHG(JSB)      + DELTA
 700 CONTINUE

     SEC = omp_get_wtime ( ) - SEC1
     WRITE(6,*) '#CPU SERIAL=', SEC, 'SECONDS.'

C---------------------------------------------------------------------
C     LEAVING SERIAL REGION


C---------------------------------------------------------------------
C    ENTERING PARALLEL REGION

     SEC1 = omp_get_wtime ( )

!$OMP PARALLEL DO

     DO K=1,KMM1
         K1 = KB1(K)
         K2 = KB2(K)
         DO J=2,JM
         JSB= JSBLK(J)
         J1 = JB1(J)
         J2 = JB2(J)

         DO I=1,IMM1
             I1 = IB1(I)
             I2 = IB2(I)
             DELTAP = STOREP(I,J,K)
             B1CHGP(I1,J1,K1) = B1CHGP(I1,J1,K1) + DELTAP
             B2CHGP(I2,J2,K2) = B2CHGP(I2,J2,K2) + DELTAP
             SBCHGP(JSB)      = SBCHGP(JSB)      + DELTAP
     END DO

     END DO
     END DO

!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

     SEC = omp_get_wtime ( ) - SEC1
     WRITE(6,*) '#CPU PARALLEL=', SEC, 'SECONDS.'


C---------------------------------------------------------------------
C     LEAVING PARALLEL REGION



C----------------------------------------------------------------------
C VERIFYING DATA CORRECTNESS 




     DO K=1,KMM1

         DO J=2,JM

             DO I=1,IMM1

                 IF(B1CHG(I,J,K).NE.B1CHGP(I,J,K)) THEN 
                    T=B1CHG(I,J,K)-B1CHGP(I,J,K)
                    WRITE(6,*) 'ERROR  ', T
                 END IF
                 IF(B2CHG(I,J,K).NE.B2CHGP(I,J,K)) THEN
                     WRITE(6,*) 'ERROR' 
                 END IF
                 IF(SBCHG(J).NE.SBCHGP(J)) THEN 
                     WRITE(6,*) 'ERROR'      
                 END IF
     END DO
     END DO
     END DO

     RETURN
     END
```

Comment: Please care about your indentation, your code is almost unreadable. If you have problems with a code you tried, show us the code, show us the wrong results and the correct results. See [ask]. Also, use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions.

Comment: The indentation is ok, this is very very old fortran code, it lives almost on statement labels. I know you are very kind to help me and it is my burden to show readeble code but re-indenting all the code is a pain. In a second I'll post the testing code.

Comment: I think you're facing a race condition on the variable `DELTA`, as it is declared outside of the parallel region.  I suggest to use `default(none)` with your OpenMP directives, as then the compiler will tell you about variables that might need to be declared with a thread-private scope.

Comment: I've tried with default(none) but nothing changed                                                       !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE) PRIVATE(K1,K2,JSB,J1,J2,I1,I2,DELTAP) 
!$OMP+ SHARED(KB1,KB2,JSBLK,JB1,JB2,IB1,IB2,STOREP,B1CHGP,B2CHGP,SBCHGP)

Comment: I tried but nothing changed. I thinking this is related to the fact that, for example, B1CHG is not accessed by loop indexes i,j,k but by indexes I1,J1,K1. Maybe they, coincidentally, have the same value in some other thread.

Comment: @VladimirF I suppose you are not used to old legacy code. Fortran compilers have the limit column set to 72 so indentation is almost never done. I indented the code anyway.

Comment: As I said, it is my burden to show readable code and you all are a very kind of persons to help me, but remain the fact that this is legacy code. Usually I don't check credentials, I base my answers on what I see and I think is strange indenting FORTRAN77 code. Probably the indented code will not run because it has exceeded the 72 characters per line limit, and it need breaking one statement line in more code lines, downgrading its readability. Anyway, as requesred by Vladimir F, I indented it! The magnitude of the errors is big, and shows some strange periodicity.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I indented the code as requested.

Comment: You say you've filled IB1, IB2, JB1, JB2, KB1, KB2 with random numbers. This is not good enough as random numbers may lead to repeated values, and hence a race condition when accumulating into B1CHG, B2CHG - these need to be decalred as reductions unless you can ensure there are no repeated values in IB1, IB2 etc.. Also the way you've used the random number generator may lead to out of bounds values.

Comment: @IanBush Why the way I implemented the random generator can lead to out of bound values ? I used FLOOR((IMM1+1)*U) to ensure that values stay beetwen 0 and IMM1 etc..I can not ensure that in the master big program I'm parallelizing there are not repeated values of IB1 IB2 etc..This is way I implemented random generator.

Comment: As I read your code all your arrays have a lower bound of 1. The random numbers as you have used them may generate entries which are zero. These are out of bounds. And if you can not guarantee different entries you are saying that the loops are not totally independent and so can not be parallelised as you have written them. That is why you need a reduction or similar.

Comment: If the problem was the out of bound values it will be present in the serial version also, but removing the omp pragmas the code run without errors when checking differences beetwen store and storep etc..how do you suggest to use reduction ? Can you show some code please ? thank you

Comment: As the others have pointed out, undeclared reduction is incorrect under omp (parallel or simd) although most compilers will handle it OK, vectorized or not, in the absence of omp directive.  omp also will ignore the possibility of repeated index values, while a compiler must take care of it if no directive is present. Perhaps others meant this to be implicit in their comments.

Comment: For an example see e.g. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION , but googling "openmp reduction" produces lots of hits, use whatever makes most sense to you. As for our of bounds your code breaks the standard and you can make no statement about expected output - please see my comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286986/do-loop-skipping-even-number/56287075. When I get time I'll also try to write an answer

Comment: @IanBush I've tried but reduction doesn't work because I've not a scalar but a vector B1CHGP etc..

Comment: OpenMP reductions for arrays have worked for years in Fortran - see e.g. slide 15 in http://www.archer.ac.uk/training/course-material/2019/06/AdvOpenMP-manch/L01-OpenMPBasics.pdf